# CAEmitterLayer draining battery

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

My project deals with IOS 12+ iPhones and i am using fire emitter to follow the finger of the user across the screen (with a pan gesture recogniser). When using the following code, i have noticed that the screen becomes warmer the game is played and it tends to drain battery more rapidly than usual the more the app is used.

Is there any particular to have a fire emitter for following a finger on the screen and yet have a battery friendly solution?

```
//set ref to the layer
 cursorEmiter = [CAEmitterLayer layer];

//configure the emitter layer
cursorEmiter.emitterPosition = CGPointMake(50, 50);
cursorEmiter.emitterSize = CGSizeMake(5, 5);
CAEmitterCell* fire = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];


fire.birthRate = 1000; // The number of emitted objects created every second. Animatable
fire.lifetime = 0.6; // The lifetime of the cell, in seconds. Animatable
fire.lifetimeRange = 0.5;

fire.color = [[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.4 blue:0.2 alpha:0.3]
              CGColor];

fire.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"PopCornSmall.png"] CGImage];

fire.velocity = 10; // The initial velocity of the cell. Animatable
fire.velocityRange = 20;
fire.scaleSpeed = 0.3;
fire.spin = 0.5;
cursorEmiter.renderMode = kCAEmitterLayerAdditive;

[fire setName:@"fire"];

//add the cell to the layer and we're done
cursorEmiter.emitterCells = [NSArray arrayWithObject:fire];
emiterNotAdded = false;
[(CAEmitterLayer *)self.layer addSublayer: cursorEmiter];
```

Comment: Where exactly is the above code located? How do you move the emitter in the gesture recognizer?

Comment: I picked up the location in the pangesturderecognizer action with     CGPoint point = [recognizerTmp locationInView:self.view]; and then set the emitter position on     cursorEmiter.emitterPosition = point;

Comment: You forgot my first question. :) Where exactly is the above code located?